# Derivative-logarithmic equivalence

Tags: calculus, statistics

In working through a survival analysis textbook, I came across the following statement:

$h(t) = \frac{-dS(t)/dt}{S(t)} $ is equivalent to $h(t) = \frac{-dlogS(t)}{d(t)} $

I can normally find my way around the integrals and derivatives necessary for understanding the probability and cumulative density functions needed for most statistical models, but I am puzzled by the above statement. Can someone help illuminate this equivalence?

If it helps, $h(t)$ is the hazard rate, defined as $h(t)=\frac{f(t)}{S(t)}$ where $f(t)$ is a probability density function, $F(t)$ its cumulative distribution function, and $S(t) = 1-F(t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply the chain rule and the derivative of $\log$:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\log(t)=\frac{1}{t}$$
$$-\frac{d}{dt}\log(S(t))=-\frac{1}{S(t)}S'(t)$$